# How can I append text to a specific column with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am attempting to call a function that appends a specific column in my google sheet with the current date. Here's my code:

https://codepen.io/afjordan/pen/LYBRGPz?editors=0010

```
    //update tasks
    function fv1Passivated() {
      var in_date = new Date();
      var str = in_date.getDate() +'/'+(in_date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+in_date.getFullYear()
  
      var params = {
          spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
          range: 'FV1!C:C', 
          valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      };

      var valueRangeBody = {
        
          "values": [
             [str]
          ]
      };

      console.log(valueRangeBody);
      var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(params, valueRangeBody);
      request.then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.result);
      }, function(reason) {
        console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    }
```

And here's what it's executing:

[image: Debug Console]

As you can see, it's appending the date to the end of the first available column instead of column C. This is indeed occurring in the sheet itself. What needs to be changed herein order to control what column gets appended?

Tried the above as described, but I also tried different values/formats for the designated range and couldn't get the data to append anywhere but the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put a value of `str` to the next row of the last row in column "C" of "FV1" sheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Javascript.
- You have already been able to get and put values for the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In the current stage, it seems that `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append` puts the value to the next row of the last row in the data range. In order to achieve your goal, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve values from column "C".
2. Retrieve the last row from the retrieved values.
3. Put the value using `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update` with the retrieved last row of the column "C".

When this flow is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var SHEET_ID = "###"; // Please set your spreadsheet ID.

gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({ spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID, range: 'FV1!C:C' }).then(({ result }) => {
  var row = result.values.length + 1;
  var in_date = new Date();
  var str = in_date.getDate() + '/' + (in_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + in_date.getFullYear()
  var params = {
    spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
    range: `FV1!C${row}`,
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  };
  var valueRangeBody = { "values": [[str]] };
  console.log(valueRangeBody);
  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(params, valueRangeBody);
  request.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.result);
  }, function (reason) {
    console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
}, reason => {
  console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
});
```

- When this script is run, the value of `str` is put into the next row of the last row of the column "C" of "FV1" sheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: Thank you so much, his was very helpful! I guess I expected the append function to work differently, but I understand what you've changed here, thank you for explaining it so well.

Comment: @Andrew Jordan About `Thank you so much, his was very helpful!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not passing the parameters correctly, could you try passing the parameters object directly?

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      "spreadsheetId": "YourSheetId",
      "range": "FV1!C:C",
      "valueInputOption": "RAW",
      "resource": {
        "values": [
          [
            "This is a test"
          ]
        ]
      }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
         // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
         console.log("Response", response);
       },
       function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); 
    });
```